# How to include same table data twice along with where clause in sequalize?

Tags: postgresql, include, sequelize.js, where-clause

Want to fetch chat details from chat table of a specific user along with the sender and recipient details(both are users of this app so users details are stored in user table)
I have tried this query

> chat table has `recipientId`, `senderId` `message`, `created_at` & `updated_at`.
>
> `id` // is nothing but user id, he can a sender or recipient

```
 const result = await models.chat.findAll({
            where: {
                $or: [{
                    senderId: {
                        $eq: id
                    }
                }, {
                    recipientId: {
                        $eq: id
                    }
                }]
            }, include :[{
                model:models.User,
                as:'User'
            }]
        })
```

With the above query, I am getting only recipient user details but I would like to get both user details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go , you can do that **by defining the diff alias with associations** :

```
chat.belongsTo(User, {as: 'sender', foreignKey : 'senderId'});
chat.belongsTo(User, {as: 'recipient', foreignKey : 'recipientId'});

await models.chat.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [{
            senderId: { $eq: id }
        },{
            recipientId: { $eq: id }
        }]
    }, 
    include :[ 
        { model:models.User , as:'sender' },
        { model:models.User , as:'recipient' }
    ]
})
```

Comment: @Schüler , glad to know :)